# Integrating Python with PingFederate

Tags: python, ping, pingfederate

Our application is written in python. I would like to integrate this with PingFederate. Is there any python library I can use for this purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

While there's no Python library commercially available from Ping Identity, there are a few options including using the PingFederate Agentless Integration Kit (https://support.pingidentity.com/s/marketplace-integration-details?recordId=a7i1W0000004ICWQA2), or a standards based protocol (like OpenID Connect - for which there are open source libraries).

The "right" choice requires further analysis based on the goal of your integration and the integration effort you wish to undertake. Ping Identity does have a more detailed guide that should help you: https://www.pingidentity.com/content/developer/en/resources/application-integration-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

I have had success integrating a few python applications with ping federate. Most recently using OpenID Connect and Flask-OIDC. Really anything you find that is SAML\Oauth\OIDC compliant shouldn't have a problem integrating with pingfederate.

http://flask-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/